# Quotient of an affine scheme

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes

Let $A$ be a ring and let $X:=\mathsf{Spec} \: A$. If $R$ is a n equivalence relation over $X$, then  is the quotient $X/R$ again the spectrum of some ring? If in general it is not, what are the assumptions I need to do about $R$ in order to get $X/R=\mathsf{Spec} \: B$ for some ring $B$?

Comment: Do you have a special case in mind ? Already where $G$ is a group acting on $X = A^n$, there are very few cases where $X/G$ is a spectrum of a ring. So if you take an arbitrary relation the answer is something like "almost never".

Comment: No I have no special cases in mind. I'm just fascinated by this topic :)

Comment: Ok. I would suggest to look at "invariant theory" and "geometric invariant theory", e.g the book by Mukai, "Invariant and Moduli".

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3608

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice class of example : if $G$ is a finite group and $X$ affine then $X/G = \text{Spec}(\Bbb C[X]^G)$.

In fact, it is almost accidental, usually for a "nice" algebraic group (i.e linearly reductive) and an linear action $G \times X \to X$ where $X$ is a vector space, then $\text{Spec}(\Bbb C[X]^G)$ will parametrize the closed orbits in $X$. More precisely there is a map $X \to X//G := \text{Spec}(\Bbb C[X]^G)$ coming from  the inclusion $\Bbb C[X]^G \subset \Bbb C[X]$, and there is a unique closed orbit in each fiber of this map (for this see Mukai, *Introduction to Invariants and Moduli*, chapter 4).

This shows that there is very little hope to expect something more general to hold true.